# Redfield quantum master equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, fermions, conductors, tight-binding

In the framework of Redfield [Quantum Master Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_master_equation), the popular approach is to use a tight-binding model linear conductor for the modeling of the Fermionic bath. Does someone can refer me to more advanced and realistic conductor implementation, which take into account various physics properties of the electrode itself and just assuming a non-interacting electrons model?

Comment: What do you mean by "physics properties of the electrode itself"?

Comment: You may be interested in this article: http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.0195 It studies exact solutions of Redfield with free fermions and even time-dependent cases

Comment: "Quantum master equation" is much too general a title for this question. Please edit the title to be specific to the question you are actually asking.